# Slideshow PHP coding - images display erratically

Tags: php, dynamic, slideshow, populate

I am trying to set up a dynamically auto-populating slideshow, but I don’t understand what’s wrong with my code. I know that both codes work separately—I tested them out. One of the codes works with a non-dynamic related directory. As for the dynamic aspect, I tried it out (without any CSS or anything else, and all pictures from the folder appear).

I know there must be a problem with how I’m coding it, but I can’t put my finger on what I’m doing wrong. I know it has to do with the PHP aspect I incorporate within the slideshow div with the class name “box_skitter box_skitter_large”.

The code I have is the following (it’s all in the body):

```php
<?php
    //path to directory to scan.
    $directory = "images/";

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
    $imgs = '';

    // create array
    foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

    //shuffle array
    shuffle($imgs);

    //select first 20 images in randomized array
    $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_skitter_large").skitter();
    });
</script>
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <?php 
            //display images
            foreach ($imgs as $img) {
                echo "<img src='$img' />";
            }
        ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is it that is actually "erratic" , what is the actual issue with the code that you have displayed on the page here?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm a little OCD on code format and layout, you have various parts of excess coding that are just not needed:

```
<?php
    //this assumes the path is <current PHP file location>/images/<image files>
    $directory = "images/";

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob( $directory . "*.jpg");
    $imgs = array(); //this may have been causing you problems, view below...

    // create array
    foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = $image; }
    unset($image);

    //shuffle array
    shuffle($imgs);

    //select first 20 images in randomized array
    $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_skitter_large").skitter();
    });
</script>
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <?php 
            //display images
            foreach ($imgs as $img) {
                echo "<img src='".$img."' />";
            }
            unset($img);
        ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What was wrong was that you had established that `$imgs = '';` which set that $img was a **string** type, and then in the `foreach` loop you had set `$imgs[] =` which implied that the `$imgs` was of an **array** type. Try it now....